# Unable to open Protected View Excel file in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to open an Excel file of population data which I downloaded from the internet into a Pandas data frame. While the Excel file is **not** password protected, it does default to some kind of "Protected View" when I open the file manually:

[image]

Clearly, I can just "Enable Editing" by using the button shown here through the GUI. But when I try and read the file into a Pandas data frame using a simple code like this...

```
import pandas as pd
my_df = pd.read_excel('2021 Total Population.xlsx')
my_df.head()
```

I get the following error:

```
UserWarning: Workbook contains no default style, apply openpyxl's default
  warn("Workbook contains no default style, apply openpyxl's default")
```

I'm fairly certain this is because of the "Protected View" setting that came with this file. But the other SO posts I could find relating to this problem were for password-protected Excel books, which this is clearly not. Again, I can manually open & edit the file, I am just wondering if I can force Pandas to do the same?

Comment: Not much of an answer, but could you try opening and saving the excel file and then opening it in python?
Also, does the file contain other tabs in it

Comment: Yes, I definitely can open it and save it as a .csv then read it in without a hitch. However, I'll likely have 10 or more of these Excel files downloaded, so I really don't want to manually open up each one, save as .csv, and then read them in as a data frame. And no other tabs in the file, just 1.

Comment: I have the same annoying issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @SimonC: unfortunately, no.